# Generalize a formula for an entire list of lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix

I want to do this

```
firstdates = dates[0]
paystring = []
for i in range(len(payment_months)):
    if payment_months[i] < firstdates[i]:
        paystring.append(0)
    else:
        paystring.append(((payment_months[i] + 12 - firstdates[i]) + 1) % 12)
print(paystring)
```

But I want to do this for all the dates which is a list of lists. For example lets just focus on the first two rows of dates.

```
print(dates[0:2])
```

gives me

```
[[8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 11, 10, 10, 8], [7, 6, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 11, 10, 10, 9]]
```

and

```
print(payment_months)
```

gives me

```
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9]
```

Then after running this:

```
paystring = []
for i in range(len(payment_months)):
    paystring.append([])
    for j in range(len(dates[i])):
        if payment_months[i] < dates[i][j]:
            paystring[i].append(0)
        elif NDD_day[j] > 1:
            paystring[i].append((payment_months[i] + 12 - dates[i][j]) % 12)
        else:
            paystring[i].append( ((payment_months[i] + 12 - dates[i][j]) + 1) % 12)
print(paystring[0:2])
```

I should get this:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]]
```

But I get this instead:

```
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Can someone help me fix my code?

Here is a handwritten example that should be very clear:

[image]

I tried changing my code to this:

```
# Calculate paystring
paystring = []
for i in range(len(payment_months)):
    paystring.append([])
    for j in range(len(dates[i])):
        if payment_months[i] < dates[j][i]:
            paystring[i].append(0)
#         elif NDD_day[j] > 1:
#             paystring[i].append((payment_months[i] + 12 - dates[j][i]) % 12)
        else:
            paystring[i].append( ((payment_months[i] + 12 - dates[j][i]) + 1) % 12)
print(paystring[0:2])
```

which gave me this:

```
[[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Hopefully that helps a bit, I am not sure why this is confusing perhaps I am not explaining this the best.

Comment: Can you explain in words, as opposed to code, what you want to achieve? If your code isn't doing what you want, then we need to know what you think it should be doing.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds sure let me make an edit

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I made a post with a picture that should give a clear understanding of what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: You (almost verbatim) just copied what code you had and put it on a piece of paper. I don't think that's what Alexander Reynolds was getting at. Use *plain English* to describe what you want. Do not appeal to code, that means no loops, no indexes (like `i`), nothing like that. *Describe* what you want to do instead. Your code is clearly wrong in some facet, so you can't describe the problem with code. It's extremely unclear (to me at least) what you're actually trying to do. "I expect this but get this", but *why* do you expect one over the other?

Comment: @MattMessersmith It is difficult to explain in words it would be easy if I explained in person but its not possible

Comment: @MattMessersmith I think it is odd that this is not clear to you I feel like its really easy to see with the examples I provided, if you wrote it out by hand it should be simple

Comment: The interpreter isn't lying to you. I mean, you're saying you want <some snippet>, you entered <some snippet>, and it gave you the <correct result> of <some snippet>. But your description of the problem is when I enter <some snippet> I expect <some random result> and I got <correct result>. Do you see the confusion? You're describing the problem circularly with code that obviously isn't doing what you expect, but it's not clear *why* you expect something different. Maybe step through each item/row one by one and show what you're trying to do on a smaller example?

Comment: Your code *looks fine*. There is nothing really wrong with it. But we can't read your mind to say *why* you expect that code to produce a particular result that it isn't producing.

Comment: I have to agree with the OP this is really simple mathematically speaking, I don’t know python but this could be easily done in C++

Comment: You really should try to explain what your input is and how you want to transform it to get the desired output. It is not clear why your desired output looks like it does. Why is this the desired output?

Comment: Also, why did you switch the order of the indices on the last snippet? You almost certainly want `[i][j]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around with it for a bit, it eventually become apparent you're using the wrong index for your `payment_months` and are iterating over the wrong `range` if you want each row in `dates`.

Setup:

```
In [35]: dates

Out[35]:
[[8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 11, 10, 10, 8],
 [7, 6, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 11, 10, 10, 9]]

In [37]: payment_months
Out[37]: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9]
```

Then we have:

```
paystring = []
for i in range(len(dates)): # len(payment_months) -> len(dates)
    paystring.append([])
    for j in range(len(dates[i])):
        if payment_months[j] < dates[i][j]: # Switched from i to j
            paystring[i].append(0)
        else:
            paystring[i].append( ((payment_months[j] + 12 - dates[i][j]) + 1) % 12) # Switched from i to j
```

outputs:

```
In [42]: paystring
Out[42]: [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]]
```

as desired.

You can actually avoid the problem entirely by just being a bit more Pythonic (avoid indices, just access elements). This also makes it clearer that each row in `dates` corresponds 1-to-1 with the `payment_months`:

```
paystring = []
for date_row in dates:
    paystring.append([])
    for date, payment_month in zip(date_row, payment_months):
        if payment_month < date:
            paystring[-1].append(0)
        else:
            paystring[-1].append( ((payment_month + 12 - date) + 1) % 12)
```

HTH.

Comment: Could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487499/subtracting-dates-from-a-list-and-each-row-from-a-list-of-lists It is pretty much the exact same answer you gave but it is different since I have different types now